# how to display old datetime-local value in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

how to display old datetime-local value in laravel ? in database i have datetime data with format 2021-09-29 14:07:00, and now i want to show datetime data when open edit page.

I've tried displaying datetime data with code like below, but still not working.

```php
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="datetime">Datetime</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="datetime" class="form-control @error('datetime') is-invalid @enderror" id="datetime" value="{{old('datetime') ? old('datetime') : Carbon\Carbon::parse($data->datetime)->isoFormat('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A')}}">
    @error('datetime')
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {{ $message }}    
    </div>
    @enderror
</div>
```

[image]

what is the correct way to display it? thx

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by "still not working" i.e. is it showing the correct date on load but not after submission, is it not showing correctly on load but it is after submission, it isn't displaying anything, it isn't display the correct format (please say which one or both), etc.?

Comment: The date input `value` needs to have the date formatted in ISO 8601 format and you're providing a different format

Comment: @Rwd sorry, I mean, date value can't show in input.

Comment: Did you try to change the format from `MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A` to `Y-m-d\TH:m` ?

Comment: @MihaiMatei no, instead I want to display it in the format MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A so that it can appear in the input.

Comment: Well, you can't. According to the [datetime-local element documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) the display format can't be set, but it is decided based on the user's locale reported by their operating system: the displayed date and time are formatted according to the user's locale as reported by their operating system, whereas the date/time value is always formatted YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm.